# Verb meaning "Verbally correct"? [Translating "Regañar" from spanish]

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, translation

Talking with my spanish colleagues one used the word `Regañar` and explained that it means 'tell someone what they are doing wrong', like telling a child to correct their behavior.

Can anyone think of any English words that translate more literally than `browbeat`, `verbal smackdown`, `set them straight`?

Google translate says `quarrel, argue, complain` which my colleagues agree is not correct

Comment: I thought of another: "Dress down"

Comment: And *rebuke*, although that's fancy. All these words are fancy.  You need a simple word, go for *scold*.

Comment: Got some extra context from my colleagues: `regañar` implies **punishing criticism**, so nothing so far is a literal translation (because you could  admonish/scold/rebuke someone for small offenses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Admonish* might be the correct word. See also words like *chastise*, *chide*, *reprimand*, and *scold*.

Comment: "Scold" is how I usually translate "regañar" from Spanish to English. For a slightly softer feel, one could also use simply "correct." As in "Don't scold/correct me" / "No me regañes."

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else that's suggested works, you could also use **discipline** as a verb:

> verb: to train (someone) to obey rules or a code of behavior, using punishment to correct disobedience.

You could discipline a child for their bad behavior, for example.